# How to change the content of email verification email in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase authentication for my app in android studio and I wanted to send the user a verification code instead of a link but firebase doesn't allow the editing of a message in email verification. It only allows the editing of the URL. So I was wondering if anyone knows a different way to edit it?

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

For security reasons those emails are currently not editable. If they were, they could easily be abused to send spam.

We're working on a way to keep that security and make them editable. But as usual: we make no promises or timelines on when that may/will be available.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comment. Is there any way to display the verification code on the landing page pehaps?  I tried experimenting with the action code but I haven't found an elaborate documentation on that.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to generate the verification code without sending an email. But there is nothing special about the code that Firebase Authentication generates, it's just a random number. If you're thinking of sending your own email, you might as well generate your own verification code.

Comment: @Frank If editing isn't allowed, perhaps we should have more variables like %APP_NAME% to work with? For me using it in the signature, as opposed to using, like say, our company name, isn't the best fit.